# Flex - Air "nativeprocess not supported"

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I want to fix the error when am using "nativeProcess" class it giving error, How to resolve the error.Any air installation failed?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html), NativeProcess is only supported with extendedDesktop profile via Native Installer

In clear text, you must have this in your appName-app.xml

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

And export your application as an .exe file (or whatever your system is), not an .air file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you running with needed privileges?
2. Did you do exactly as in [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process.html)?
3. What kind of process you are trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into such issue when i was using wrong adobe air sdk. As you know, native process support was introduced in 2.0 adobe air sdk. But i used Adobe Flash Builder plug-in for Eclipse, and Eclipse was pointing to 1.5. Manual replacement of air files in the sdk folder with ones in the Air 2 SDK and pointing Eclipse to the right sdk fixed the problem. See detailed description here:

http://www.selikoff.net/2010/06/28/installing-the-adobe-air-2-sdk-in-eclipse/

If you are using the appropriate air sdk, ensure that you've included "extendedDesktop" profile to the "supportedProfiles" section in your application descriptor file.